# Laravel Where Condition on Grand Parent Eloquent Relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have 4 tables:

```
Account (id, name)

Type (id, account_id, name)

Category (id, type_id, name)

Money (id, category_id, date, amount)
```

And I defined the relations at model

But my problem is how to get money data with account id 2?

```
Account::find(2)-> type()-> category()->money
```

Is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you created your relationships, you can do it this way:

```
$account = Account::with('type.category.money')->find(2);
```

and to display money you can now use:

```
echo $account->type->category->money->amount;
```

In above `echo` I of course assume for each record you have data in all those tables. If not, you'll need to add extra checking to make sure you don't display property for `null`

Answer (score 2):

You can also go about this from the other direction if you only need the final result of 'money' and have the inverse relationships setup on the models.

```
$money = Money::whereHas('category.type.account', function ($q) use ($id) {
    $q->where('id', $id);
})->get();

// get() or first() depending whether these relationships return many
```

[Laravel Docs - Eloquent Relationships - Querying Relationships - Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)